# ¿Qué significa la sintaxis nombe[:,:,:]=0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz, sintaxis

Hola mi pregunta es simple, quiero saber más menos detalladamente que significa esto

```
rojo[:,:,1]=0
rojo[:,:,2]=0

verde[:,:,0]=0
verde[:,:,2]=0

azul[:,:,0]=0
azul[:,:,1]=0
```

Sé que estas son 3 copias de una matriz esta matriz es una imagen, y con estas tres copias yo saco las matrices de los tres planos rgb de la imagen, pero **el problema es que no conozco lo que hace la sintaxis** `variable[:,:,:]=0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Introducción

Esta técnica es conocida como slicing, es una tecnica que puede ir desde lo más sencillo `matriz[1]` hasta lo más complejo `imagen_rgb[2:, :1, ::2]`.

Es **muy util al trabajar con conjuntos de datos** ya que te puede ahorra tiempo y muchas lineas de programación. Mi recomendación es que practiques con varios ejercicios hasta dominarlo a la perfeccción.

### 2. Explicación

Primero vamos a reproducir tu problema:

```
import numpy as np

imagen_rgb = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
```

La variable `imagen_rgb` es una matriz `3x3x3` que imita una imagen, en concreto es así:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Sí ejecutamos `imagen_rgb[0]` **estaremos seleccionando las matrices**, en concreto la primera de ellas, por lo que el resultado sería:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Por lo tanto, la primera posición del indice selecciona el elemento principal, en este caso, la primera matriz.

Como sabemos, las matrices son vectores que pueden ser vectores fila (filas) y vectores columna (columnas). Por lo que Python (y la mayoría de lenguages) da la posibilidad de hacer este tipo de seleciones. Si ejecutamos `imagen_rgb[:, 1]` obtendremos:

```
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23]])
```

Como explicamos antes, la primera posición se corresponde a las matrices, usando `:` le hemos indicado que coja todas las matrices, y después usando `1` le indicamos las filas, por lo que le hemos dicho **"de todas las matrices, cogeme la segunda fila de cada una de ellas"**

Pero ¿Y si queremos indicar las columnas? Pues obviamente tenemos que seguir con esta notación. Si usamos `imagen_rgb[:, :, 1]` obtendremos lo siguiente:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  7],
       [10, 13, 16],
       [19, 22, 25]])
```

Esta notación quiere decir algo así como **"De todas las matrices, teniendo encuenta todas las filas, cogeme la  segunda columna de cada una de ellas"**.

Obviamente esta notación se puede usar para coger exactamente los elementos que quieras, por ejemplo imaginate que queremos hacer lo mismo que antes, pero excluyendo la última fila, ejecutamos `imagen_rgb[:, :-1, 1]` y obtendremos lo siguiente:

```
array([[ 1,  4],
       [10, 13],
       [19, 22]])
```

Una vez explicado todo esto, para completar la respuesta, el resultado de ejecutar la expresión de tu pregunta`imagen_rgb[:, :, 1] = 0` da el siguiente resultado

```
array([[[ 0,  0,  2],
        [ 3,  0,  5],
        [ 6,  0,  8]],

       [[ 9,  0, 11],
        [12,  0, 14],
        [15,  0, 17]],

       [[18,  0, 20],
        [21,  0, 23],
        [24,  0, 26]]])
```

Le has indicado, **"selecciona todas las matrices, y cogiendo todas las filas, selecciona la segunda columna, y todos estos datos conviertelos en cero"**

### Bonus

- Como te he comentado es bueno dedicarle unas horas a esto para entenderlo, porque te va a ahorrar mucho tiempo en el futuro. Hay una gran cantidad de recursos, explicaciones y ejercicios en internet sobre **slicing e indexing**
- Otra buena técnica de aprendizaje, es hacer lo que acabamos de hacer en esta explicación, crearte una matriz sencilla ordenada, y ver los cambios que se van produciendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la excelente explicación me quedo todo claro, ahora a seguir aprendiendo.